# Javascript prototype and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this example:

```
wofForm = function( $form ) {
  this.form   = $form;
  this.select = this.form.find(".sm-product-select");
  this.productChange();
}
wofForm.prototype.productChange = function() {
  this.select.on("change", **this.checkIfVariableProduct** )
}
wofForm.prototype.checkIfVariableProduct = function() {
  console.log("searching ", this );
}
```

Why when I pass the `this.checkIfVariableProduct` inside productChange it's actually passing the select object, instead of wofForm instance? I would like to pass the wofForm instance further, not the jQuery object of the select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` value of the handler is set by jQuery's `on` method. "When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered." For setting the `this` value manually you can use the `Function.prototype.bind` or `$.proxy` method.

```
 this.select.on("change", this.checkIfVariableProduct.bind(this) );
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question

Comment: An example using `$.proxy`, as mentioned, would be a nice addition to this good answer.